# Нужна ли запятая в данном предложении? (4)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

*Он относится ко мне(,) как к товару.*

Comment: Розенталь: https://i.imgur.com/uNtBXt2.png

Comment: Привели пример бреда от Розенталя, чтобы подтвердить мой ответ? Когда кто-то кому-то брат, то никто не говорит: ‟Я относился к нему как к брату”. А пример: ‟Он работал как батрак” – в одном случае это в качестве оборот, с чем всё и так ясно. Зачем Розенталь так делал?! Зачем он смешивал примеры из разных пунктов?! Сначала он скажет, что если сравнительный оборот – сказуемое, то он не обособляется, а потом будет добавлять такие примеры в другие пункты. Зачем так делать?! Он был умственно отсталым?

Comment: Ещё как говорят. К брату можно относится не как к брату, а как ко врагу. У Розенталя всё логично и правильно, а если вы не можете понять, то ясно, кто умственно отсталый, для таких он, увы, не разжёвывал.

Comment: Тогда это будет не в значении ‟он мне родной брат”, а в значении ‟близкий друг”. Во всех случаях это будет в значении ‟близкий друг”.  Розенталь написал здесь полную чушь.

Comment: Нет, это не чушь, но можно было лучше пояснить. Здесь разница только в том, брат или нет на самом деле. Нельзя сравнивать с братом, если он брат на самом деле.

Comment: В обоих случаях, приведённых вами, это в значении ‟близкий друг”.

Comment: По пунктуации можно определить, брат он на самом деле или нет. А значение роли не играет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никто не знает, как правильно обособлять сравнительные обороты. Розенталь написал какой-то полубред по этой теме, а лингвисты, будучи недоумками, не понимают, что это полубред. Но даже если представить, что это не полубред, то получается ситуация, когда никто не знает, как обособлять эти обороты. Если бы лингвисты были хотя бы не полными идиотами, то они сказали бы, что что это за пунктуация, в которой никто не разбирается, зачем кому-то такая пунктуация, давайте введём предписание или давайте перепилим вообще всё по новой. То есть нет вообще никаких вариантов, что эти люди не полные идиоты.

**Дополнение на тему: как быть?**
Есть проблема только с этим моментом, когда сравнительный оборот относится к глаголу (с остальными ситуациями всё ясно). Просто ставьте запятую только тогда, когда сравнительный оборот не является характеристикой действия, как в предложениях: ‟Я спал на улице, как бездомный”, ‟Утки стали подниматься в воздух, как на прощание”, ‟Она знала в какое место ужалить, как пчела”. И не ставьте запятую всегда, когда сравнительный оборот является характеристикой действия, как в предложениях: ‟В доме коменданта я был принят как родной”, ‟Токорев со вчерашнего вечера чувствовал себя как в похмелье”, ‟Всюду на меня смотрели как на умалишенного”, ‟Он относится ко мне как к товару”. А если кто-то скажет, что вы ошиблись, то просто скажите человеку, что он неправильно трактует термины ‟образ действия”, ‟уподобление”, ‟приравнивание”, ‟отождествление”. Такие термины ничего не значат без детального и аккуратного пояснения, чего в этом быдлосправочнике нет и близко.

Comment: И как быть тогда?

Comment: Я дополнил.....

Comment: Характеристики действия точно нет, неверный термин.

Answer (score 0):

А лучше так:

Если отсутствуют какие-то отчётливые инструкции по этой теме, то мы можем просто написать их сами, но таким образом, чтобы они не противоречили каким-то отчётливым официальным пунктам. Это отличный способ решения этой проблемы. Мы можем написать предписания такие, чтобы, когда человек будет писать по ним, никто не мог сказать, что он ошибся. Это будет не трудно, так как в том же справочнике Розенталя по этой теме написан по большей части откровенный бред.

Вот моё правило по этой теме: сравнительные обороты всегда обособляются, кроме случаев, когда они являются сказуемыми или устойчивыми сочетаниями, или являются в качестве оборотами, стоящими в конце предложения и не имеющими причинного значения, или перед сравнительным оборотом стоит частица. Проблема решена! Никто не сможет уличить в ошибке человека, который будет писать по такому правилу.
**Крайний даунизм лингвистов создаёт проблему, но он же и разрешает её.**

В итоге правильный ответ: ‟Он относится ко мне, как к товару”.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141763/discussion-on-answer-by-jim-korbett-------4).

Comment: Вы отвергаете вариант без запятой, это и есть вольная трактовка.

Comment: @Ajgy Не отвергаю, просто он маловероятен. Если она его собственность (может, он султан), то без запятой.

Comment: У меня не поднимется рука поставить в данном предложении запятую. Образа действия я здесь не вижу, как в случае с батраком. Выбор делается между значением "в качестве" и "уподоблением". Однако в пользу того, что запятая не нужна, говорит и тот факт, что имеется смысловая недостаточность сказуемого, сравнительный оборот тут явно не к месту.

Comment: @Ajgy Понимаю, но всегда в приоритете устранение двусмысленности. Поэтому тесная связь со сказуемым уходит на второй план. Розенталю следовало уделить больше внимания этому моменту.

Comment: В школах действует такое пунктуационное правило: если оборот можно заменить на "в качестве", то запятую не ставим, и никто не думает ни о какой двусмысленности.

Comment: И вы до сих пор не объяснили. Почему "он работал, как батрак" и "он работал много" - это одно и то же? В первом случае запятая есть, во втором - нет. Наречие не располагает к запятой.

Comment: @Ajgy В школе обычно продвинутые вещи не учат. "В качестве" не всегда нормально подставляется. Надо смысл понимать (есть отождествление или нет). "Являться" хорошо помогает, но напрямую он не подставляется. Розенталь просто смысл показывает, "как батрак" подразумевает, что много. Да, оттенок образа действия тоже имеется, но он тоже уходит на второй план.

Comment: Понимаю, что в школе многое опускается, однако само предложение выглядит странно с запятой. Я о том, что для проверки используют замены: образ действия - на творительный падеж, наречие, а сравнение - на "подобно, словно", тут же "много" отнесли к сравнению (с запятой).

Comment: @Ajgy На второй план здесь уходит образ действия, из-за двусмысленности, то художественное, на смысле не сказывается, то есть не критично, если не показываем образ действия. Не так уж странно, паузу там можно сделать.

Comment: А почему не сделать образ основным значением? А сравнение опустить на второй план?

Comment: @Ajgy Потому что тогда двусмысленность: либо он брат, либо он как брат. А это самое зло.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, почему в данном случае "образ" идет в группу сравнения. Ведь он должен идти в группу "вкачестве"

Comment: @Ajgy Есть только два варианта: с запятой и без. Нет возможности показать третий вариант. В английском есть два слова, там проще, с двумя словами можно было бы сделать аж четыре варианта. И ещё одна проблема. У нас есть: сравнение, которое может быть образом действия, и отождествление. То есть образ по своей природе относится к сравнению.

Comment: Это так.Я говорю о том, что знаки препинания должны различать сравнение и образ, но они в данном случае в одной группе. Как так?

Comment: @Ajgy Не совсем в одной группе. Просто мы не показываем образ. Нет средств, всё занято. Вынужденная мера. А он и не сильно важен. Откуда он вообще взялся? Просто порой паузы вообще не звучат, поэтому запятые не ставят, то есть он просто произношение отображает.

Comment: Просто тогда непонятно, зачем Розенталь включил в список это" много", он мог просто написать: "Подобно брату".

Comment: @Ajgy Ну он просто не думал, что у кого-то из-за этого возникнут проблемы. "Подобно батраку" и "много" — это почти то же самое. Разница в паузах. Именно отсутствие пауз и интонация сближают с наречием.

Comment: Понятно теперь. Спасибо

Comment: @JimKorbett "Всегда, кроме случаев" — это не грамотно. Не надо говорить, что всегда, если на самом деле не всегда. Грамотный вариант: *обособляются, за исключением случаев* (так пишут в справочниках). Уже второй раз говорю.

Comment: OleeDD, ответьте, пожалуйста, на мой вопрос (неполнота предложения).

Comment: @Ajgy Не занимаюсь классификациями, не вижу в них никакого смысла. Я не в теме. А какой смысл в этом видите вы? Меня интересует только то, что связано с грамотностью.

Comment: Я тоже бы не занимался, но приходится иметь с ними дело, так как постоянно с учениками над этим работаем.

Comment: @Ajgy Теперь всё ясно)